# Analysis on data txt.files

Tags: python-3.x

I have a series of .txt files that I want to analyse all at the same time. The files are typically having a lenght of about 1000 values. I want to analyse the first 200 values of them on outliers. An outlier is whenever the value is below 12. Therefore I use the code, however, I get the error:
'numpy.bool_' object does not support item assignment. How to overcome? Should I not use loadtxt in order to perform these kind of checks?

```
for files in document:
    Rf_file = open(files, "r")
    Rf_value = np.loadtxt(Rf_file)

    #Indicate outliers

    for i in range(0,200):
        outliers = Rf_value[i] < 12
        Rf_value = Rf_value[outliers]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3RRW.png)

Comment: Can you add an example file and an example output?

Comment: I added an image to my discription, if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an example, it is hard to give a perfect answer, but the answer is most probably something like this:

```
import numpy as np

for document in documents:
    values = np.loadtxt(document)
    values_200 = values[:200]
    outliers = values_200[values_200 < 12]
```

Comment: values_200 = values[:200] 
This is indeed the way to go instead of using a for loop. Thank you.